# SVG Xlink:href particular URL gives an error

Tags: svg, xlink

I'm new to SVG coding and trying to create an xlink:href attribute to a path.
The link works with a standard URL but not the one the client wants to go to.
The link supplied works fine from the supplied word document but not in the SVG code. Other paths links are working fine.
URL is https://pdms.hw.ac.uk/index.php?Mode=Search&CourseID=4251
any thoughts?

example 1: This function works.

```
<a xlink:href="https://pdms.hw.ac.uk/" xlink:show="new">
    <ellipse
       style="opacity:0;fill:white;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#008080;stroke-width:2.60064602;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="CoverplateSchedule"
       cx="68.767662"
       cy="238.28044"
       rx="13.467875"
       ry="13.685399"   />
    <g
       id="g2556"
       transform="matrix(0.23470858,0,0,0.21678373,57.533146,227.46417)">
      <path
         id="path2552"
         d="m 76,32 v 8 H 68 V 32 Z M 20,68 h 8 v 8 H 20 Z M 40,32 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,0 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,20 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 0,12 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m -24,4 h 8 v 8 h -8 z m -4,0 v 8 H 32 V 68 Z M 32,56 h 8 v 8 h -8 z m -4,0 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 0,-12 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,8 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 8,12 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 8,-32 v 8 H 56 V 32 Z M 14,26 V 82 H 82 V 26 Z"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <rect
         id="rect2554"
         height="8"
         width="68"
         y="14"
         x="14" />
    </g>
     <ellipse
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#008080;stroke-width:2.60064602;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path1959-9-3-2-2-6-3-9"
       cx="68.767662"
       cy="238.28044"
       rx="13.467875"
       ry="13.685399"   />
  </a>
```

Example 2: Error saying not well formed

```
   <a xlink:href="https://pdms.hw.ac.uk/index.php?Mode=Search&CourseID=4251" xlink:show="new">
    <ellipse
       style="opacity:0;fill:white;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#008080;stroke-width:2.60064602;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="CoverplateSchedule"
       cx="68.767662"
       cy="238.28044"
       rx="13.467875"
       ry="13.685399"   />
    <g
       id="g2556"
       transform="matrix(0.23470858,0,0,0.21678373,57.533146,227.46417)">
      <path
         id="path2552"
         d="m 76,32 v 8 H 68 V 32 Z M 20,68 h 8 v 8 H 20 Z M 40,32 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,0 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,20 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 0,12 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m -24,4 h 8 v 8 h -8 z m -4,0 v 8 H 32 V 68 Z M 32,56 h 8 v 8 h -8 z m -4,0 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 0,-12 v 8 h -8 v -8 z m 12,8 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 8,12 h -8 v -8 h 8 z m 4,0 v -8 h 8 v 8 z m 8,-32 v 8 H 56 V 32 Z M 14,26 V 82 H 82 V 26 Z"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <rect
         id="rect2554"
         height="8"
         width="68"
         y="14"
         x="14" />
    </g>
     <ellipse
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#008080;stroke-width:2.60064602;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path1959-9-3-2-2-6-3-9"
       cx="68.767662"
       cy="238.28044"
       rx="13.467875"
       ry="13.685399"   />
  </a>
```

Error message
[Error messagein Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RF39.png)

Comment: @RobertLongson I've added a couple of examples to the description. Hopefully something simple I am doing wrong.

Comment: Still get the error

Comment: As soon as I try to use the link "https://pdms.hw.ac.uk/index.php?Mode=Search&CourseID=4251", which works from word or simply pasting it into the address bar I get the 'not well formed error. If I remove everything after pdms.hw.ac.uk/ the graphic works and links.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It points to a web page, which you can see from the link in the comment above.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but I have enclosed the SVG in Html brackets and the link now works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is what you have posted the whole SVG(s)?  SVGs should have a root element of `<svg>`.  Do yours start with an `<a>`?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, no its not the whole file as this is fairly large, only the element giving me issues.

Comment: The URL in the error you posted has a double `//` in the wrong place.  Try fixing that and see if it makes a difference. I.e. `.ac.uk/index.php`.

Comment: Can't see that double //

Comment: Look in the screenshot containing the error.